# Changing a library path in Netbeans

Tags: c++, macos, netbeans, include-path, dyld

I'm trying to run my C++ code in Netbeans but It gives me the following error:(It is compiled successfully)

> *dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libdiscpp.10.dylib*

I can run it on terminal(mac), because I set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to what I wanted but in Netbeans I can't . I changed it as an environmental variable like this :

> *DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/nima/dislin*

but it gives me the same error. anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your NetBeans project type is general `C/C++ Application`:

- Open project properties
- In the left pain open the `Build` sub-tree, then click on `Linker`
- In the right pane find `Additional Library Directories` line, then click on its chooser (a little square with three dots on the right)
- In the popup window which opens you will be able to choose any (existing) directory you want to add to your library search path

[image: Project Properties]

A new project configuration will be created after that (by default you have only `Debug` and `Release` configurations) - don't forget to make it current when you compile and link.

I'm not in OSX, but the sequence should be the same.